# Extra String while decrypting AES encrypted message

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography, aes

I have implemented Android code to decrypt AES message. I have a problem with the result. I saw there were extra obj in the output String. How to get rid of these obj? When I tried to copy the obj from debugging mode, it became empty String. I have also tried by trimming the string but doesn't work. I have attached the screeshot
[image: Decrypted String with OBJ tag]

[image: Log Message]

Comment: can you post it though the Log cat ?, there is very good chance someone has encrypted the JSON it self

Comment: In logcat, OBJ changes to space. I tried by using trim, it doesn't work.But while populating in textView, it becomes again OBJ as like in Screenshot

Comment: @PankajNimgade  I have updated my question.Please find the logcat. Thank you

Comment: do you know the actual message before it was encrypted ?

Comment: yes @PankajNimgade I know :)

Comment: Is the en / decrypter using a padding scheme? Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING")

Comment: when you decrypt something some extra characters are added to the string. This happens with me when I decrypted otp from webservice. To get your original string just use toString() method on that variable

Comment: @SlipperySeal I did but result is same :(